# In UE5, how exactly can I create a cinematic camera which follows a vehicle with view from driver seat?

Tags: unreal-engine5

How exactly can I drive a vehicle in UE5 and have a camera in the driver view/seat?

I'm attempting to use the Unreal Engine 5 Sample city demo, specifically the vehicle test map.

From what I understand, this is a cinematic camera that would need to be offset in some way? What are the steps required to get a cam setup to track a vehicle, and to test the above scenario? I could use SampleCity, or even just start with a basic template if there are some instructions to get that camera setup in that way.

Answer (score 0):

- In play mode (press green play button) then your actor just gets in and drives the
  car (google that)
- to animate it, do that through 'sequencer' it will play, but to record it you need 'take recorder' active. add a cinecamera and position in POV driver, either
  1. add the cam in blueprint and check 'expose to cinematics'  or
  2. add the cam to scene, then add to 'sequencer' and animate via 'transform'
  to move with the car, setting movement from point A to point B on
  sequencer timeline or you can move cam along a 'spline' or rail track etc for
  more complex shot movement.
  that's the process, just google for details